# W3C валидация css написанного scss — какие есть оффлайн инструменты для проверки?

Tags: css, css3, gulp, sass, scss

**Ситуация:**

Есть проект с SCSS и сборкой на Gulp.  Верстальщики используют Sublime и VSCode.
Ищем удобные инструменты проверки валидности css.

**Идеальный вариант:**

- линтер в ide верстальщика, который прямо в SCSS файле показывает ошибки в CSS. 
- плюс npm модуль, который можно повесить на precommit (с поддержкой sourcemap - чтоб показывал ошибки прямо в scss файле)

**Какие вообще есть варианты решений?** 
Пока нашли только scss-lint, но вроде проверяет только ошибки комплияции SCSS и codestyle. 
Тоже хорошо, но мало - можно написать нерабочий код css который проходит проверку.

Comment: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/DOWNLOAD.html.en ?

Comment: интересный способ, но в нашем случае важна реализация на npm, без Java

Comment: npm? Может, Node.js? В любом случае, странное требование, когда из кода на Node.js можно свободно запускать Java.